# Change selected Items style || multiselect dependency Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The Question sounds dumb,
but I cant figure out how to change the style of the selected Items
in the [Multiselect](https://pub.dev/packages/multiselect/example) dependency.

My Widget looks like this:

```
DropDownMultiSelect(
    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    selectedValues: gewaehlteArten,
    whenEmpty: "",
    options: arten,
    onChanged: (List<String> specificArten) {
      setArten(arten: specificArten);
    });
```

What can I do?

Here an additional picture:

[image]

I want to change the color to any other except of white ;)

Answer (score 1):

`DropDownMultiSelect` has prop called `menuItembuilder` and use that and you can change style based on currently selected values

```
DropDownMultiSelect(
hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
selectedValues: gewaehlteArten,
whenEmpty: "",
options: arten,
menuItembuilder: (option){
  if(gewaehlteArten.contains(option) return YOUR_SELECTED_WIDGET;
  return NORMAL_WIDGET;
},
onChanged: (List<String> specificArten) {
  setArten(arten: specificArten);
});
```

You can also use `childBuilder` to make menu completely custom.

Comment: could you change ur solution by refactoring menuItemBuilder to childBuilder, thats the property I needed